# How to split value to another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data input and want output in picture. How do I to write it?

i can run in sql server for this but i get only width column( w_pacakaging) , but i dont know to write get value length or high from column text (db name : [Packing list text])

my code is

```
    select [Packing list text],[Grade],[sales doc no], 
 case when [Packing list text] like'%:%' then 
  cast(Ltrim(Rtrim(SUBSTRING([Packing list text], charindex(':', [Packing list text]) + 1, charindex('"', [Packing list text])  

  - (charindex(':', [Packing list text]) + 1)))) as [nvarchar] ) 
                       END AS [W_packaging] 
 from [TPC_CRSYS].[dbo].[TotalOrder_Export]
```

the result from sql server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FANup.jpg)

How could you advice me for write sql to get data for length and heigh from table [TotalOrder_Export] because it has more than one x in each record

could anyone advice me

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Many products have their own, non-ANSI SQL, string handling functions.

Comment: Please be more specific. You get precise answers if you write precise questions.

Comment: i can run in sql server for this but i get only width column, but i dont know to write get value length or high from column text

Answer (score 1):

the easy way using CTE and **CHARINDEX**:

```
;with
T AS ( -- select the base table, adding an index for performances pourpose
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [sales doc no],[Packing list text]) ROW_IDX
    FROM [TPC_CRSYS].[dbo].[TotalOrder_Export]
),
W AS (-- SELECT ONLY ROWS WITH VALID DIMENSIONS AND CALC WIDTH POSITION
    SELECT *, CHARINDEX('(WXLXH): ', [Packing list text])+9 W_POS 
    FROM T
    WHERE CHARINDEX('(WXLXH): ', [Packing list text])>0
),
L AS (-- CALC LENGTH POSITION
    SELECT *, CHARINDEX('"', [Packing list text], W_POS)+2 L_POS 
    FROM W
),
H AS (-- CALC HEIGHT POSITION
    SELECT *, CHARINDEX('"', [Packing list text], L_POS)+2 H_POS 
    FROM L
),
X AS (-- CALC 
    SELECT *, CHARINDEX('"', [Packing list text], H_POS) END_POS 
    FROM H
)
SELECT T.[Packing list text], T.grade, T.[sales doc no]
, SUBSTRING(T.[Packing list text], W_POS, L_POS-2-W_POS) W
, SUBSTRING(T.[Packing list text], L_POS, H_POS-2-L_POS) L
, SUBSTRING(T.[Packing list text], H_POS, END_POS-H_POS) H
FROM T
LEFT JOIN X ON T.ROW_IDX = X.ROW_IDX
```

alternatively, you can use **OUTER APPLY** and a split (**FN_SPLIT**) function to get w/h/l in rows for each [Packing list text], and then **PIVOT** them back to one single line:

```
;with
T AS ( -- select the base table, adding an index for performances pourpose
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [sales doc no], [Packing list text]) ROW_IDX
    FROM [TPC_CRSYS].[dbo].[TotalOrder_Export]
),
W AS (-- SELECT ONLY ROWS WITH VALID DIMENSIONS AND CALC WIDTH POSITION
    SELECT *, CHARINDEX('(WXLXH): ', [Packing list text])+9 W_POS 
    FROM T
    WHERE CHARINDEX('(WXLXH): ', [Packing list text])>0
),
spl as (
    select W.ROW_IDX, d.*
    from w
    outer apply (
        select ID, SUBSTRING(data,2,100) VAL
        from FN_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(w.[Packing list text], w_pos-1, 100),'"') s
        where s.id<=3
    ) d
),
X AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM spl
    PIVOT (MIN(VAL) FOR ID IN ([1],[2],[3])) P
)
SELECT T.[Packing list text], T.grade, T.[sales doc no], X.[1] W, X.[2] L, X.[3] H
FROM T
LEFT JOIN X ON T.ROW_IDX = X.ROW_IDX
```

this second version is faster if you have many rows in your [TotalOrder_Export] table

for the split function, you will find many versions around, I made this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SPLIT]
(
    @Line varchar(8000),
    @SplitOn varchar(10) = ','
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, -- VERY USEFUL TO MAKE JOINS AND TO CREATE THE UNIQUE INDEX ON SPLITTED STRINGS
    Data varchar(800) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (DATA, ID) -- THIS WILL MAKE REALLY FASTER THE QUERIES USING THIS FUNCTION
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Line IS NULL RETURN

    DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn+'X')-1 -- TO CATCH TRAILING SPACES PROBLEM WITH LEN()
    DECLARE @line_len INT = LEN(@line+'X')-1
    DECLARE @start_at INT = 1
    DECLARE @end_at INT
    DECLARE @data_len INT

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        IF @start_at > @line_len BREAK;
        SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @Line, @start_at)
        SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN @line_len ELSE @end_at-@start_at END
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) VALUES( SUBSTRING(@Line,@start_at,@data_len));
        SET @start_at = @start_at + @data_len + @split_on_len
    END

    RETURN
END
```

I hope this helps